# Discord.py adding reaction to webhook.send message

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am able to send messages to my discord channel via webhook very easily, however, when trying to add reactions to the messages it's very difficult, considering my programming is still trivial.

The code line I have right now is:

```
data_count=1
webhook.send(content=discord.Reaction(message="test", data=data_count, emoji=""), file=discord.File("american_eagle_excited.gif"), embed=discord.Embed(title="Sample Embed", description="This is the description"))
```

Everything, when I break down the parameters I can get to work besides the **discord.Reaction** class. I feel like I am missing something very easily and after trying to read through the class requirements I had to finally make my way to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

To add a reaction you need the `discord.Message` instance which is returned by the `webhook.send` method, you then add the reaction with `message.add_reaction`

```py
message = webhook.send("test", wait=True, ...)  # `wait=True` is really important, if we don't set this the bot will not wait for the message to be returned
await message.add_reaction("")
```